# "User is unauthorized" error with sample web viewer app

Tags: bentley-itwin

I'm following the instructions here: https://www.itwinjs.org/learning/tutorials/develop-web-viewer/ to create a sample web viewer app. The doc says to update variable IMJS_CONTEXT_ID which is not in the .env file and doesn't appear with "Show IDs" for my iModel (I have created a github issue for the doc already). I've tried updating the variable IMJS_ITWIN_ID instead with the "iTwin ID" from my iModel. When I start the app I get an error page "An Error Has Occurred: The user is unauthorized. Please provide valid authentication credentials". I have checked the variables IMJS_AUTH_CLIENT_CLIENT_ID, IMJS_AUTH_CLIENT_REDIRECT_URI, IMJS_AUTH_CLIENT_SCOPES, IMJS_ITWIN_ID, IMJS_IMODEL_ID and all appear to be correct. Is there something else I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the tutorial you're referring to is a bit outdated now. Have you taken a look at https://developer.bentley.com/tutorials/web-application-quick-start/?
In the new @itwin/web-viewer-react templates we renamed IMJS_CONTEXT_ID to IMJS_ITWIN_ID. We also made some changes to the required scopes, you'll need namely `imodelaccess:read`, `imodels:read`, and `realitydata:read`. Please make sure your auth client has the above scopes and you have access to the model. If you still have trouble, feel free to continue the discussion over at https://github.com/iTwin/itwinjs-core/discussions

Comment: Thanks, I'm not able to add those scopes to the app registration, only itwinjs and imodelaccess:read are available to select. Will that cause a problem?

Comment: In your App's registration at https://developer.bentley.com/apps/spa/{your-client-id}/, go to API Association > Add APIs > Digital Twin Management. Add both iModels and Reality Data associations. From there you should see the individual scopes required.

Comment: I have the same problem, "Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript`", and have tried to add apis, but the problem does not disappear ; have you managed to solve ?